# Rails: has_many with condition on self

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations

I'm trying to have a condition on a has_many clause referencing to the current model but I'm getting an error:

```
PG::Error: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "badges"
```

This is my model:

```
class Badge < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :user_badges, :dependent => :destroy  
  has_many :users, :through => :user_badges, :conditions => ["(user_badges.era_id =? and badges.seasonal =?)", GAME_CONFIG["current_era"], true, GAME_CONFIG["current_era"], false]
end
```

Can you point me in the right direction?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
has_many :users, -> { select(badges.*, users.*).where("user_badges.era_id =? and badges.seasonal =?", GAME_CONFIG["current_era"], GAME_CONFIG["current_era"]) }, through: :user_badges
```

Comment: Thanks Rick but something seems missing before "-> { select(badges.", also I haven't seen before the "->" operation.  BTW on this app I'm still using Rails 2.3.

Comment: Oh jesus I didn't know it was Rails 2.3 `->` is a Rails 4 function [Check this post](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html) & search for "Customizing The Query"

Comment: I believe my syntax is correct for Rails 4, but since you're on Rails 2.3, it won't work. The key is to use the `select()` to help it load the badges data

Comment: Thanks Rick, I'll try this way!

Comment: I cannot find much about using select() in a Rails 2.3 association.  Do you think it is possible in someway?